# To find the nth Derivative of $9\sqrt{x}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Can you help me to proof that the nth derivative of $9\sqrt{x}$ is $$ (-1)^{(n-1)} \cdot \frac{9(2n-2)!}{(n-1)!} \cdot (4x)^{\frac{1-2n}{2}}$$

I've tried induction but didn't go very far.

Many thanks

Comment: Easiest way will be to find first, second, third and may be 4th derivative and see if you can generalise it.

Comment: Induction works. Take the derivative of your formula and show that it becomes the same formula, but with $n$ replaced by $n+1$.

Comment: I don't thin the four belongs there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Induction is a very good way. For the induction step,

Say $P(n)$ is true for $n=k$ 
For $P(k+1)$, $$\frac{d}{dx^{k+1}}(9\sqrt x)$$
$$=\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{d}{dx^{k}}(9\sqrt x)\right)$$
$$=\frac{d}{dx} \left[(-1)^{(k-1)} \cdot \frac{9(2k-2)!}{(k-1)!} \cdot (4x)^{\frac{1-2k}{2}}\right]$$
$$=(-1)^{(k-1)} \cdot \frac{9(2k-2)!}{(k-1)!} \cdot \frac{d}{dx} \left[(4x)^{\frac{1-2k}{2}}\right]$$
$$=(-1)^{(k-1)} \cdot \frac{9(2k-2)!}{(k-1)!} \cdot \frac{1-2k}{2}  (4x)^{\frac{-1-2k}{2}}\cdot 4$$
$$=(-1)^{[(k+1)-1]} \cdot \frac{9(2k-2)!}{(k-1)!} \cdot (2k-1)  (4x)^{\frac{-1-2k}{2}}\cdot 2$$
$$=(-1)^{[(k+1)-1]} \cdot \frac{9(2k-2)!}{(k-1)!} \cdot (2k-1) \cdot \frac{2k}{k} \cdot (4x)^{\frac{-1-2k}{2}}$$
$$=(-1)^{[(k+1)-1]} \cdot \frac{9[2(k+1)-2]!}{[(k+1)-1]!} \cdot (4x)^{\frac{1-2(k+1)}{2}}$$

$P(k+1)$ is true.

Comment: Induction is what makes more sense to me. I got to half of this but you got me through the place where I was stuck.

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: In your 5th line you are multiplying by 4. How did you do that? If I split the power, as a product I will not get the same.

Comment: I am not multiplying by $4$. I differentiated the entire expression first with respect to $4x$ and then differentiated $4x$ with respect to $x$ to get $4$. Get it? If you split the power as a product, you will get the same. Consider the exponent of $4$. If you split the power as a product, power of $4$ will remain same i.e.  $\frac{1-2k}{2}$ and in my working, add the exponents of $4$, you will find it same. Clear??

Comment: Well I got what you did but still don't understand how splitting it into $4^{\frac{1-2k}{2}} . x^{\frac{1-2k}{2}}$ does not produce the same. Nevertheless, moving on, I do not understand how you go from $(1-2k )$ to $(2k-1)$ and the exponent of $(-1)$ goes from $(k-1)$ to $[(k+1)-1]$. Thanks

Comment: For the first thing that you were talking of, it produces the same even on splitting the power as product. And for the second thing, I actually take $(-1)$ common from $(1-2k)$ and multiply it with $(-1)^{k-1}$ to get $(-1)^{k}$ and $(k+1)-1=k$.

Comment: Hi, Can you also explain the last step where you multiply and divide by k, and how it affects the factorial? Thanks

Comment: Do you mean the second last step? Thats where I have done so.

Comment: Yes, which will produce the last equation.

Comment: I simply multiply $2k(2k-1)$ with the numerator and $k$ with the denominator to get the respective factorials and then I have arranged them accordingly. Is it okay?

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, the 9 is unimportant. Induction is the correct way to proceed, but perhaps we can disguise it in a computation:

$$\begin{align} \frac{d^n}{dx^n} \left( x^{\frac{1}{2}} \right) &= \frac{d^{n-1}}{dx^{n-1}} \left( \frac{1}{2} x^{\frac{1}{2} -1} \right) \\&= \frac{d^{n-2}}{dx^{n-2}}\left( \frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{1}{2} - 1 \right) x^{\frac{1}{2} -2} \right) \\&= \dots =\frac{d^{n-k}}{dx^{n-k}} \left( \frac{1}{2} \left( \frac{1}{2} -1\right) \left( \frac{1}{2} -2 \right)\dots \left(\frac{1}{2} -(k-1) \right) x^{\frac{1}{2} - k}\right) \\&= \frac{1}{2} \left( \frac{1}{2} - 1 \right) \left( \frac{1}{2} -2 \right)\dots \left(\frac{1}{2} - (n-1) \right) x^{\frac{1}{2} -n }. \end{align} $$ Can you simplify this?

Answer (score 2):

Writing the first four derivatives of $f(x)=x^{1/2}$ reveals

$f^{(1)}(x)=\frac12 x^{-1/2}$

$f^{(2)}(x)=\frac12 \left(-\frac12\right)x^{-3/2}$

$f^{(3)}(x)=\frac12 \left(-\frac12\right)\left(-\frac32\right)x^{-5/2}$

$f^{(4)}(x)=\frac12 \left(-\frac12\right)\left(-\frac32\right)\left(-\frac52\right)x^{-7/2}$

We propose the general term is given by

$$f^{(n)}(x)=(-1)^{n-1}\left(\frac12\right)^n (2n-3)!!x^{-(2n-1)/2}$$

Then, the $n+1$ derivative

$$\begin{align}
f^{(n+1)}(x)&=(-1)^{n-1}\left(\frac12\right)^{n}(-1)\left(\frac12\right) (2n-1)(2n-3)!!x^{-(2n-3)/2}\\\\
&=(-1)^n\left(\frac12\right)^{n+1}(2n-1)!!x^{-(2n-3)/2}
\end{align}$$

which provides proof by induction!

Comment: This is really not a proof...the OP probably did this and deduced the formula. He/she is looking for a proof.

Comment: @rogerl One can easily use induction using the expression of the general term, can one not?  And why on earth did you single my answer out as others have posted similarly.

Comment: Sure, but that's what the OP is having trouble with.

Comment: @rogerl I added a bit more to provide the inductive step.  Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give the best answer I can.

Comment: Yes, I think that addresses the OPs question.